# Single select <g:select> is producing more than one "selected" item by default

Tags: grails, gsp, html-select

I have a `<g:select>` in one of my GSPs that looks like this:

```
<g:select id="location" name="criteria.location" from="${example.Location.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="1" class="many-to-one"/>
```

The expected result would be something like this, right?

**Expected result:**

```
<select id="location" name="criteria.location" required="" class="many-to-one" >
    <option value="1" selected="selected" >1st Location Name</option>
    <option value="2" >2nd Location Name</option>
    <option value="3" >3rd Location Name</option>
    <!-- entries omitted -->
    <option value="49" >49th Location Name</option>
    <option value="50" >50th Location Name</option>
</select>
```

But what do I get? I end up with *two* selected items. The 49th option gets selected as well, and I cannot begin to imagine why! There is absolutely *no* mention of the value "49" in my code...

**Actual result:**

```
<select id="location" name="criteria.location" required="" class="many-to-one" >
    <option value="1" selected="selected" >1st Location Name</option>
    <option value="2" >2nd Location Name</option>
    <option value="3" >3rd Location Name</option>
    <!-- entries omitted -->
    <option value="49" selected="selected" >49th Location Name</option>
    <option value="50" >50th Location Name</option>
</select>
```

If I change the `value` in my `<g:select>` to "3" for example, the 3rd option gets selected, but for whatever reason the 49th item still gets selected as well.

**Edit:** Even more bizarre, if I change the `value` property to a value *greater than* 49, the select works and only the nth option is selected!

**Update:** I posted an answer detailing how I got it working, but I still do not understand the original behaviour of the `<g:select>` tag.

Does anyone have any idea as to what is going on here?

---

**Grails version:** 2.2.0

Comment: The option 49 is selected by "1" because "1" has a ASCII value of 49 (I just spent half my work day tracking the same bug. Arghhhh)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use value attribute for it

```
value="${location ?: 49}"
```

e.g.

```
<g:select id="location" name="criteria.location" from="${example.Location.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${location ?: 49}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Comment: This is similar to what I did, but I still do not understand why my original `value` resulted in multiple selections. Can you explain this to me?

Comment: @Stephan I don't see problem in this code. May be problem somewhere in another part of code

Comment: Any clue as to what kind of logical error could result in this? I'm quite new go Grails, and moreover there isn't a lot more code than that...

Answer (score 4):

I know I'm a bit late, but I had this issue today.
First of all, I believe it's a bug actually, don't know if it's been reported, but maybe has to do with data types.
Your approach works fine, but only when we don't need to make a value selected dynamically. For that, just cast the binded value as Integer (Long, or whatever the type you are looking for), like this:

```html
<g:select id="location" name="criteria.location" from="${example.Location.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${yourVarName as Integer}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

Can be used after **fieldValue** too.
I hope it can help someone, and answers your question about why is this happening. But indeed, it should be reported as a bug.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out how to make it work, but I still cannot explain how the behaviour of the `<g:select>` tag. I changed the `value` property to "${1}" instead of "1", like this:

```
<g:select id="location" name="criteria.location" from="${example.Location.list()}" optionKey="id" required="" value="${1}" class="many-to-one"/>
```

I presume the tag was interpreting my value as a String instead of a number, but I still do not see how the `<g:select>` tag can allow a select control that is *not* a multiselect to have more than one selected item by default. To me, this looks like a bug.

Comment: "1" is 49 (in ASCII). "${1}" is the number 1.